# Merge two xml files based on common attribute

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, merge

I have two xml files with a similar structure, and I need to merge them based on a common attribute. To be more explicit, here are two samples:

file1.xml

```
 <Products>
 <record ProductId="366" ProductName="Test" ProductCategory="Categ1"></record>
 </Products>
```

file2.xml

```
 <Productprices>
 <record ProductId="366" ProductPrice="10" ProductVAT="24"></record>
 </Productprices>
```

The common attribute in both files is ProductId. I need to merge all the attributes so that the combined file would look like this:

```
 <Products>
 <record ProductId="366" ProductName="Test" ProductCategory="Categ1" ProductPrice="10" ProductVAT="24"></record>
 </Products>
```

Unfortunately, all I have managed to do so far is simply merge the two files, the merged file looks like this:

```
 <Products>
 <record ProductId="366" ProductName="Test" ProductCategory="Categ1"></record>
 <record ProductId="366" ProductPrice="10" ProductVAT="24"></record>
 </Products>
```

This is the PHP code I used:

```
 $doc1 = new DOMDocument();
 $doc1->load('file1.xml');
 $doc2 = new DOMDocument();
 $doc2->load('file2.xml');
 $res1 = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('Products')->item(0);
 $items2 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('record');
 for ($i = 0; $i < $items2->length; $i ++) {
 $item2 = $items2->item($i);
 $item1 = $doc1->importNode($item2, true);
 $res1->appendChild($item1);
 }
 $doc1->save('file1.xml');
```

Is there any way I can merge all the attributes into one record based on the common ProductId by using DomDocument? I would rather not go into XSLT.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Xpath to fetch nodes and values from DOM. In your case I see two tasks.

One task to iterate all record elements in on document, fetch the attributes of the matching element from the second document and copy the attributes.

The other task to iterate all record elements in the second document and add them to the first if here is no element with that ProductId.

```
$xmlOne = <<<'XML'
<Products>
 <record ProductId="366" ProductName="Test" ProductCategory="Categ1"></record>
</Products>
XML;

$xmlTwo = <<<'XML'
<Productprices>
 <record ProductId="366" ProductPrice="10" ProductVAT="24"></record>
 <record ProductId="444" ProductPrice="23" ProductVAT="32"></record>
</Productprices>
XML;

$targetDom = new DOMDocument();
$targetDom->loadXml($xmlOne);
$targetXpath = new DOMXpath($targetDom);

$addDom = new DOMDocument();
$addDom->loadXml($xmlTwo);
$addXpath = new DOMXpath($addDom);

// merge attributes of record elements depending on ProductId
foreach ($targetXpath->evaluate('//record[@ProductId]') as $record) {
  $productId = $record->getAttribute('ProductId');
  foreach ($addXpath->evaluate('//record[@ProductId='.$productId.']/@*') as $attribute) {
    if (!$record->hasAttribute($attribute->name)) {
      $record->setAttribute($attribute->name, $attribute->value);
    }
  }
}

// copy records elements that are not in target dom
foreach ($addXpath->evaluate('//record[@ProductId]') as $record) {
  $productId = $record->getAttribute('ProductId');
  if ($targetXpath->evaluate('count(//record[@ProductId='.$productId.'])') == 0) {
    $targetDom->documentElement->appendChild(
      $targetDom->importNode($record)
    );
  }
}

echo $targetDom->saveXml();
```

Comment: Looks good, however I've run into a slight problem (I am quite new at this). I am trying to load the two xml files like this: $xmlOne = '/var/www/html/test/file1.xml' and $xmlTwo = '/var/www/html/test/file2.xml' but I get the following error in php: DOMDocument::loadXML() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in ... I've tried everything I could find to turn the xml object into a string but I can't get anything to work. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thank you very much.

Comment: DOMDocument::loadXml() is for xml strings, DOMDocument::load() for xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attribute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) function of SimpleXML

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
foreach($xml->Products->record->attributes() as $attribute => $value) {
    //do something
}
```