# Merge two xml files in one xml files with php

Tags: php, xml

I have two XML files whose structure is the same but the content is different.

I tried to use many approaches but I could not find the right answer.

**XML 1:**

```
<Products>
<Product>
<Prdocut_Code>12345</Prdocut_Code>
<Prdocut_Desc>Product desc</Prdocut_Desc>
</Product>
</Products>
```

**XML 2:**

```
<Products>
<Product>
<Prdocut_Code>12345</Prdocut_Code>
<Prdocut_Price>12.5</Prdocut_Price>
</Product>
</Products>
```

How can I show the product code, description and price in the same file according to the product codes in a different single XML file, considering the multiple products in the XML files in this structure?

Comment: Provide the output you expect as well.

Comment: Experienced friends normally expect you to first do your best and try to write some code, then if you have problem in your code, come here and share your code with us. SO is not a _Write code for me_ service. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse both XML files, find common nodes, and then merge their leaves. At last, you build and write the new XML to a file.

You need to utilize an XML parser. PHP itself provides you with [one](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). You can also utilize the [`DOMDocument`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class or even [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22082361/65732). Or if you want a cleaner API, there is the [Orchestral's XML Parser](https://github.com/orchestral/parser).

And good news for you; there's a 5 years old [PHP XML merge script](https://github.com/samarthp/xml-merge) out there, if you don't want to write the solution yourself.